# How many characters can I store in an NVARCHAR(4000) on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting confused. Does the NVARCHAR(4000) refer to the number of characters I can have in that field or do I have to do some conversion for this? I already realize that the NVARCHAR occupies twice as much space per character but I am still not sure how many characters maximum in the 4000.

Comment: 4000 characters. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx): "n defines the string length ... The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`nvarchar(4000)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) can store 4000 UCS-2 characters:

> Variable-length Unicode string data. `n` defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000.